# What does this mean in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi please am new to python coming from a visual basic .net framework. Trying to follow a tutorial on http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog2.html. There is a line of code i really don't understand. Please can someone explain it to me. Thanks

```
 import time
 from calendar import month_name
 year, month = time.localtime()[:2]
```

The confusion for me is that the variable year and month is their value both time.localtime()[:2].
Any clarification will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The function returns more than 2 values; the first two values are sliced off (see duplicate) and assigned to the two variables on the left.

Comment: When in doubt, try things out in the Python interpreter. Try `time.localtime()` for example.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters i get it now. Very thankful for your help.